# Bootstrap for Longitudinal/Repeated Measures Data?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap

This is a problem I have been curious about for some time now.

Suppose:

- There is a coin where if it lands head then the probability of the next flip being heads is 0.6 (and if tails then the next flip being tails is also 0.6)
- There are 100 students in a class
- Each student flips this coin a random number of times
- The last flip of student_n does not influence the first flip of student_n+1 (i.e. when the next student flips the coin, the first flip has 0.5 probability of heads or tails, but the next flip for this student depends on the previous flip)

Here is some R code to represent this problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
ids <- 1:100
student_id <- sort(sample(ids, 100000, replace = TRUE))
coin_result <- character(1000)
coin_result[1] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)

for (i in 2:length(coin_result)) {
  if (student_id[i] != student_id[i-1]) {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)
  } else if (coin_result[i-1] == "H") {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1, prob = c(0.6, 0.4))
  } else {
    coin_result[i] <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1, prob = c(0.4, 0.6))
  }
}

#tidy up
my_data <- data.frame(student_id, coin_result)
my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$student_id),]

final <- my_data %>%
    group_by(student_id) %>%
    mutate(flip_number = row_number())
```

The data looks something like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   student_id [1]
  student_id coin_result  flip_number
       <int> <chr>              <int>
1          1 H                      1
2          1 H                      2
3          1 H                      3
4          1 H                      4
5          1 T                      5
6          1 H                      6
```

**My Problem:** In this scenario, let's say that I do not have any prior knowledge about this coin (i.e. I only have access to the data from the students) and I think its possible that the coin might have "correlated probabilities"  - particularly, I think the result of the previous flip might influence the next flip. To test this hypothesis, I can count the number of sequences observed:

```
final %>%
    group_by(student_id) %>%
    summarize(Sequence = str_c(coin_result, lead(coin_result)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
    count(Sequence)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Sequence     n
  <chr>    <int>
1 HH         253
2 HT         186
3 TH         182
4 TT         279
```

From these results, it seems like the result of a coin flips appears to be influenced by the previous flip - however, **I am interested in placing Confidence Intervals around these estimates.**

I know that in general, this type of problem is characterized by a Multinomial Distribution (e.g. if the coin had more than two sides) and that there are exact formulae for Confidence Intervals based on the Multinomial Distribution. However, I am interested in learning about how to use Bootstrapping in this problem.

Right away, I can see that if the standard Bootstrapping approach is used, we will likely "interrupt" the sequence of flips - that is, we might get the $n^{\text{th}}$ flip for the $j^{\text{th}}$ student immediately followed by the $n^{\text{th}}$ flip for the $k^{\text{th}}$ student , thus invalidating the estimates produced from the Bootstrapping.

The first idea that comes to mind is to modify the Bootstrapping procedure so that the sampling process is not interrupted. For example:

- **Approach 1:** Randomly sample with replacement students until you have the same number of students as the original data. Using all available data for these students, calculate the probabilities and 95% Confidence Intervals. Repeat this process $k$ times
- **Approach 2:**  Randomly sample with replacement students until you have the same number of students as the original data. For each of these students selected, randomly choose a starting point $x$ and ending point $y$ (where $y > x$), and select all available data between $x$ and $y$ for a given student. Then, calculate the probabilities and 95% Confidence Intervals. Repeat this process $k$ times.

Here is my attempt at Approach 1:

```
# Initialize 
results <- data.frame(iteration_number = numeric(0),
                      h_given_h = numeric(0),
                      h_given_t = numeric(0),
                      t_given_h = numeric(0),
                      t_given_t = numeric(0))

# Set the number of iterations
n_iter <- 1000

# Loop
for (i in 1:n_iter) {
  # Randomly sample 100 student ids with replacement
  sampled_ids <- sample(ids, 100, replace = TRUE)
  
  # Select rows for sampled students
  sampled_data <- my_data[my_data$student_id %in% sampled_ids, ]
  
  final <- sampled_data %>%
    group_by(student_id) %>%
    mutate(flip_number = row_number())
  
  # Calculate conditional probabilities
  cond_prob <- final %>%
    group_by(student_id) %>%
    summarize(Sequence = str_c(coin_result, lead(coin_result)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    filter(!is.na(Sequence)) %>%
    count(Sequence) %>%
    mutate(prob = n / sum(n))
  
  # Extract probabilities
  p_HH <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "HH"]
  p_HT <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "HT"]
  p_TH <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "TH"]
  p_TT <- cond_prob$prob[cond_prob$Sequence == "TT"]
  
  # Create a vector with the probabilities
  prob_vector <- c(p_HH, p_HT, p_TH, p_TT)
  print(prob_vector)
  # Append 
  results[i, ] <- c(i, prob_vector)
}

colnames(results) <- c("iteration_number", "h_given_h", "h_given_t", "t_given_h", "t_given_t")

library(ggplot2)
results_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(results, cols = -iteration_number, names_to = "condition", values_to = "probability")

# Plot 
ggplot(results_long, aes(x = iteration_number, y = probability, color = condition)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Iteration", y = "Probability", color = "Condition")
```

[image]

Then, based on these results - I can calculate the 95% Confidence Intervals based on the Quantile function:

```
          h_given_h_percentiles <- quantile(results$h_given_h, c(0.05, 0.95))
    h_given_t_percentiles <- quantile(results$h_given_t, c(0.05, 0.95))
    t_given_h_percentiles <- quantile(results$t_given_h, c(0.05, 0.95))
    t_given_t_percentiles <- quantile(results$t_given_t, c(0.05, 0.95))
    
    percentiles_results <- data.frame(condition = c("h_given_h", "h_given_t", "t_given_h", "t_given_t"),
                                 `5%` = c(h_given_h_percentiles[1], h_given_t_percentiles[1], t_given_h_percentiles[1], t_given_t_percentiles[1]),
                                 `95%` = c(h_given_h_percentiles[2], h_given_t_percentiles[2], t_given_h_percentiles[2], t_given_t_percentiles[2]))

# Calculate the mean for each column
h_given_h_mean <- mean(results$h_given_h)
h_given_t_mean <- mean(results$h_given_t)
t_given_h_mean <- mean(results$t_given_h)
t_given_t_mean <- mean(results$t_given_t)

percentiles_results$mean <- c(h_given_h_mean, h_given_t_mean, t_given_h_mean, t_given_t_mean)

  condition       X5.      X95.      mean
1 h_given_h 0.2973799 0.2984679 0.2979292
2 h_given_t 0.1978462 0.1981885 0.1980179
3 t_given_h 0.1977906 0.1981054 0.1979481
4 t_given_t 0.3056818 0.3065346 0.3061047
```

**My Question:** Can someone please tell if this approach to Bootstrapping Longitudinal/Repeated Measures data is statistically valid? Or is what I have done meaningless?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://pratheepaj.github.io/bootLong/articles/bootLong.html
- https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-019-01252-y
- [Bootstrapping with repeated measurements](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412440/bootstrapping-with-repeated-measurements)
- https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03202577.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.01832

**Note:** I am currently finalizing the R Code for Approach 2 - if someone is interested, I can also post it.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please tell if this approach to Bootstrapping Longitudinal/Repeated Measures data is statistically valid?

It works if the bias of the coin is assumed to be the same among the different students.

In that case the results from each student are like a repetition of the sampling/experiment and multiple samples from a population give insight into the statistical variation in the sampling distribution.

This variation can be expressed by using bootstrapping (a direct calculation would be easier, it is not clear whether this question is actually about the bootstrapping, and instead more about considering the students as independent samples that are an indication of the sampling distribution).

---

Sidenote 1: in your code you use expressions like `h_given_h`, which is not very clear language.  The frequency of HH, which you analyse, is different from the frequency of H given H, which you use in your wordings.

Example: Consider the case where the bias is fully correlated "There is a coin where if it lands head then the probability of the next flip being heads is 1 (and if tails then the next flip being tails is also 1)", then the frequencies of HH and TT will be around 0.5 (depending on the first flip being H or T), but H given H will be one, and not 0.5.

---

Sidenote 2: The method works, but is not very powerful. With the same example above, you have students with either only TT or only HH. You could have a very clear table like

```
1 HH         343
2 HT         0
3 TH         0
4 TT         479
```

But if these results are from only a few students (consider the extreme case of only 2 students, one flipped 343 HH's and the other flipped 479 TT's), then your bootstrapping will generate very large confidence intervals.

The confidence intervals express the frequencies of HH and TT, and that includes the first flip. So while you have 343 and 479 results, many different measurements, you treat the variability here as only the 2 students first flips.

Comment: @ Sextus Empiricus : Thank you so much for your answer! Are there any standard approaches that I can use for this kind of problem? If the coin had more than two sides, could I just treat this as a Multinomial Distribution and construct a Confidence Interval based on the Wald Interval using the Multinomial Distribution? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob it is related to this question about comparing transition matrices: [statistical comparison of two markov chain transition matrices](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/611747/statistical-comparison-of-two-markov-chain-transition-matrices). Why you would like apply bootstrapping to the problem I am not sure. If the your goal is to *"test this hypothesis"*, then you do not need to construct a confidence interval.